# Hadoop map reduce ignores the xmx memory defined in my java code

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I have a java map-reduce code and I used the following lines in it to define the memory heap size:

```
conf.set("mapreduce.map.java.opts", "-Xms3g");
conf.set("mapreduce.map.java.opts", "-Xmx3g");
conf.set("mapreduce.reduce.java.opts", "-Xmx2g");
```

but when I run my code, it still uses 2g physical memory and fails run some map-reduce tasks. I even changed the memory limit in yarn xml files but still get the same error. Would you please help me to figure out what the problem is and why does it ignore my memory definition?

Comment: It's been a while, but you might have to remove any tags from your site.xml file for these properties to work... I think the site.xml wins.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to define the physical memory in code, so after adding:

```
conf.set("mapreduce.map.memory.mb", "4000");
```

problem solved!